# Change grid layout depending on number of elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a wrapper that can have 1-5 elements.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to change the layout in which they're displayed depending on the number of them:

- 1 element: 1x1, 33.3% width

[image]

- 2 elements: 2x1, 33.3% width

[image]

- 3 elements: 3x1, 33.3% width

[image]

- 4 elements: 2x2, 50% width

[image]

- 5 elements: 3x2, 33.3% width

[image]

How can I do this without JavaScript?

This is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kpagcha/pen/VwXpNMe) for reference.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 2px dashed #5f5f5f;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ededed;
  flex: 33.3%;
  max-width: 33.3%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper.with-4-elements .element {
  flex: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.wrapper-with-5-elements .element:nth(4),
.wrapper-with-5-elements .element:nth(5) {
  flex: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper with-1-element">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper with-2-elements">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper with-3-elements">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper with-4-elements">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element 4</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper with-5-elements">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element 4</div>
  <div class="element">Element 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like below using CSS grid:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.element {
  grid-column: span 2;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
/* the case with 4 elements */
.element:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.element:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *{
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

And with flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.element {
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 10px)/3); /* 10px = 2 * gap */
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
/* the case with 4 elements */
.element:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.element:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *{
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 5px)/2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am adding gaps to make the answer generic but you can remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I'd appreciate if you walked us through how this solution works.

Comment: @dabadaba all the cases are the same (width: 33.33%) and you only have one case where the width is 50%. I simply wrote a specific rule to target that case and make the width different

Comment: @dabadaba the selector apply only if you have 4 element because when you have 4 elements the first-child can also be the 4th element counting from the end.

Comment: Oh I see how that works. It targets the element that is both the first child and the 4-th last child, a case that only happens when there's 4 elements. That's creative. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you, what if I wanted the 5-element case to be displayed as 2-2-1? I would use the rules `:first-child:nth-last-child(5), :nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4), :nth-child(3), :nth-last-child(3), :nth-child(4):nth-last-child(2)` to target the first two rows.

Comment: @dabadaba in my code you replace `4` with `n + 4` in the selector. It will target 4,5,6 etc but since you only have 5 then it will 4 and 5